# Duplicate Query is not Working

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am checking the duplicates Accounts, contacts but in my vf page it showing Account name. duplicate count,.

How can i change my vf,apex class to show contact and duplicate count in vf page.Along with Accounts

```
 <apex:page controller="TestMapController">
     <apex:pageblock title="Map Usage On VF">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!data}" var="d">
            <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                {!d}
            </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Duplicate Count">
               {!data[d]}
           </apex:column>
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:page>
```

Apex Class

```
public class TestMapController{    
    public map<string,integer> data {get;set;}

    public TestMapController(){
        data = new map<string,integer>();
        for(Account acc: [Select Id, Name, (Select Id, name, Email from Contacts), Phone from Account])
        {
            integer count = data.get(acc.name);           
            if(count != null)
                count++;
            else
                count = 1;
            data.put(acc.name, count);                    
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it is better to let the database do the counting rather than pulling the data out and then looping over it. That also allows the results to be easily ordered.

Using that approach, and (as in guy's example assuming you just want separate lists - not so good otherwise) the code would look like this:

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    public AggregateResult[] accounts {
        get {
            if (accounts == null) {
                accounts = [
                        select Name n, count(Id) c
                        from Account
                        group by Name
                        order by Name
                        limit 10000
                        ];
            }
            return accounts;
        }
        private set;
    }
    public AggregateResult[] contacts {
        get {
            if (contacts == null) {
                contacts = [
                        select Name n, count(Id) c
                        from Contact
                        group by Name
                        order by Name
                        limit 10000
                        ];
            }
            return contacts;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

and the Visualforce like this:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:pageblock title="Accounts">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="ar">
            <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                {!ar['n']}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Duplicate Count">
                {!ar['c']}
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageblock>
    <apex:pageblock title="Contacts">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="ar">
            <apex:column headerValue="Contact Name">
                {!ar['n']}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Duplicate Count">
                {!ar['c']}
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

and **PS** a controller test:

```
@isTest
private class MyControllerTest {

    @isTest
    static void test() {

        Account[] accounts = new Account[] {
                new Account(Name = 'Acme'),
                new Account(Name = 'Acme'),
                new Account(Name = 'Zebra')
                };
        insert accounts;

        Contact[] contacts = new Contact[] {
                new Contact(LastName = 'Smith', AccountId = accounts[0].Id),
                new Contact(LastName = 'Jones', AccountId = accounts[1].Id),
                new Contact(LastName = 'Jones', AccountId = accounts[2].Id)
                };
        insert contacts;

        MyController controller = new MyController();

        System.assertEquals(2, controller.accounts.size());

        System.assertEquals('Acme', controller.accounts[0].get('n'));
        System.assertEquals(2, controller.accounts[0].get('c'));

        System.assertEquals('Zebra', controller.accounts[1].get('n'));
        System.assertEquals(1, controller.accounts[1].get('c'));

        System.assertEquals(2, controller.contacts.size());

        System.assertEquals('Jones', controller.contacts[0].get('n'));
        System.assertEquals(2, controller.contacts[0].get('c'));

        System.assertEquals('Smith', controller.contacts[1].get('n'));
        System.assertEquals(1, controller.contacts[1].get('c'));
    }
}
```

Comment: good that you took a bit more time to actually improve the code structure. I'm voting for your answer :-)

Comment: @keith while writeing test class it showing constructor is not static can you help me how to write the test class for mycontroller.

Comment: @Sathya I've added a test to the answer.

Comment: @guy Thanks. I keep seeing code posted that ought to be using "group by" but isn't and wanted to make that point.